# Crystal Report ASP.NET Viewer and IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, crystal-reports, internet-explorer-10

There seems to be an issue with viewing Crystal Reports in ASP.NET Crystal Report viewer in IE 10.0.  I switch IE 10 in Developer Tools to run in IE 9 mode, and I can see the report then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, SAP has not gotten around to work on IE 10 / Windows 8 yet.  http://scn.sap.com/thread/3233406

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally came across a strange fix: outputting a string (other than space) 
on the form load event subsequently allows the viewer to render correctly in IE10

```
 Dim vBrowser As System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities = Request.Browser
 If vBrowser.Type = "IE10" And vBrowser.MajorVersion > 9 Then
     Response.Write(".")
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the CR XI ActiveX viewer control under classic asp. I discovered that my reports were coming up blank under IE 10. Using compatibility mode allowed the reports to work correctly. The problem was that IE 10 is apparently more picky about 'assumed' sub names for dom events such as the `window_onload` event in the `SmartViewerActiveX.asp` page that I, and probably many other people, use. In the original file from SAP, the sub is written as `Window_Onload`. (note the capitalization) There are two ways to fix this: add this text `onload="Window_Onload;"` to the body, or simply drop the capital letters in the original sub name. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this stylesheet and will fix magically:

```
.hideableFrame {
        display:none;
}
```

Happy coding :)